# Log Out from Application when Log Out from Google

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, google-api, google-oauth

I have created an express server with Google OAuth for authentication. When the user authenticates itself with Google, they automatically sign up for Google Services (eg. Gmail).

How do I configure my app such that when they log out of Google services (eg. Gmail), they also log out from my app?

```js
app.get('/auth/google/callback', async (req, res) => {
  const code = req.query.code as string
  const { tokens } = await authClient.getToken(code)
  authClient.setCredentials(tokens)
  const { data } = await google.oauth2('v2').userinfo.get({ auth: authClient })
  let user = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { googleId: data.id! } })
  if (!user) {
    user = await prisma.user.create({
      data: { googleId: data.id!, displayName: data.name! },
    })
  }
  const token = jwt.sign(user, secret)
  res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 })
  res.redirect(origin)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible.
I logged out from google in other browser and it didn't log me out from any website that i use with google login.